# Returning dynamic SQL statement in PL/pgSQL Functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, dynamic, plpgsql

I have a table called "points" with a column called "geom" of type geometry.
I want to create a function that returns a table with a column of "geometry" data type. I have been successful in returning a table with my the correct data type when the name of the target table (points) is hardcoded in the "RETURN QUERY" clause. 
I want to have the name of the table as an input of the function (in a dynamic way). How can I change this code to accept the name of the target table (called points in this code) as an input?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION milad_points()
RETURNS TABLE (geom points.geom%TYPE)
AS $$ 
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT points.geom FROM points;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I know that for managing the dynamic queries we have to make it as a string and run it as **EXECUTE sql_string**. However, I could not get it work in the above-mentioned example.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do something like that is to use the `anyelement` data type.
But in order to use `anyelement` as a return type, you have to specify an `anyelement` parameter too. It is not important what value you use as argument, but its data type determines the actual data type returned.

See the following example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION anyfun(tabname name, typdef anyelement) RETURNS SETOF anyelement
   LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$$BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT id FROM %I', tabname);
END;$$;
```

Now let's test it with two different tables:

```
CREATE TABLE anytab (id integer);
INSERT INTO anytab VALUES (1), (42);

SELECT * FROM anyfun('anytab', NULL::integer);

 anyfun 
--------
      1
     42
(2 rows)

CREATE TABLE anothertab (id text);
INSERT INTO anothertab VALUES ('one'), ('two');

SELECT * FROM anyfun('anothertab', NULL::text);

 anyfun 
--------
 one
 two
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, I did not know that we can use "RETURN QUERY EXECUTE + sql_string".

I think it gives a wide range of flexibility and for sure will solve my problem.